# postgresql silent installation issue with powershell

Tags: powershell, postgresql-9.4

I am doing unattended installation of `postgresql-9.4.4-3-windows-x64`, using this command with `Invoke-Command`:

```
postgresql-9.4.4-3-windows-x64.exe --unattendedmodeui minimal --mode unattended --superpassword "password" --servicename "postgreSQL"
--servicepassword "password" --serverport 5432
```

But the issue is the visual studio GUI is popping up. If no one has logged in to the server, the installation is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the change in the parameters:

From:

```
--unattendedmodeui minimal
```

To:

```
--unattendedmodeui none
```